# ScrollView/WebView flickering

Tags: java, android

I have a application that uses a WebView inside a ScrollView inside a LinearLayout. The purpose of the ScrollView is to scroll past part of the web page and prevent the user to scroll to other portions of the page. However this causes a large amount of flickering in the background while the app is idle.

I've tried just about every relevant post I could find, but nothing I found works.

Code for the Scroll View:

```
 //Scrolls past the header
    final ScrollView alertScroll = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.alertScroll);
    alertScroll.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            alertScroll.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    alertScroll.scrollTo(0,100);
                }
            });
        }
    });



    //Keeps user from scrolling
    alertScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

content_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/verticalIguess"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scaleType="fitXY">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/alertScroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:scaleType="fitXY">


        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/AlertMap"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        </WebView>


    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you try with `NestedScrollView`? According to your layout, the `RelativeLayout` is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. When I did that I got the error `Timed out waiting for process to appear on emulator-5554`